# Specific font-weights not working

Tags: css, html, fonts, sass

I have a _fonts.scss file in my app with the code shown below. When trying to see if the font-weight 400 applies, nothing happens. However, font-weights like 300, 500 and 900 work. I tried to find a solution but to no avail. What could be causing this?

```
   @font-face {
        font-family: ProximaNova;
        src: url("../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
        font-weight: 400;

    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: ProximaNova;
        src: url("../fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.otf") format("opentype");
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: ProximaNova;
        src: url("../fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.otf") format("opentype");
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: ProximaNova;
        src: url("../fonts/ProximaNova-Light.otf") format("opentype");
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: ProximaNova;
        src: url("../fonts/ProximaNova-Thin.otf") format("opentype");
        font-weight: lighter;
    }
```

[UPDATE]

It seems ProximaNova-Thin always replaces ProximaNova-Regular when seen in the Fonts tab of Chrome's dev tools. Why can't I keep both?

Comment: Did you try setting `font-weight: 400` for ProximaNova-Regular?

Comment: Yes I did. But still same.

Comment: Can you provide a MCVE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It’s hard to diagnose the issue just from the code above, which looks correct. FWIW, you may want to consider using `woff` and `woff2` instead of `otf` due to their smaller size.

Comment: you set font-weight:300 to use ProximaNova-Light.otf, and font-weight:500 to use ProximaNova-Semibold.otf, but you didn't set a font for font-weight:400...  so what exactly do you expect to appear when you style an element with font-weight:400?

Comment: I use `font-family: "Proxima Nova";` - space between `Proxima` and `nova`

Comment: It seems ProximaNova-Thin always replaces ProximaNova-Regular. I see that in the chrome Network Fonts tab. Why would that happen?